# Return boolen from two counts on same table

Tags: mysql, sql

From the same table, what would be a good way to do two different selects and generate a Boolean based on the results.

**testable**

```
pKey | prodStatus
-----------------
1    |   0
2    |   0
```

**I'm trying to do this**

```
select count(pKey) from testable where pKey = 1 and prodStatus = 0
along with
select count(pKey) from testable where pKey = 2 and prodStatus = 0

If both results where 1 then `true` else `false`
```

Right I do this using php and a lot of code because I've no idea how its done purely in sql and something like this is complete beyond me. How can I do something like this in sql itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN pKey = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
     = SUM(CASE WHEN pKey = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM testable
WHERE prodStatus = 0
```

Based on Barmar's answer, except (1) he has `AND` where I think you want an `=` and (2) not all DBs allow the implicit conversion of boolean to 1/0. This is more portable, and will work if someone using a different DB lands here with Google.

The query planner *may* be smart enough to optimize two queries with subselects into just one pass over the table, but I wouldn't bet on it.

**[edit]** left out the `END` in first version.

Comment: Does this work with MySql? I keep getting: `/* SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') = SUM(CASE WHEN pKey = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0) FROM testable WHERE prodStatus = 0' at line 1 */`

Comment: Ach! Left out the "END" in the case!

Answer (score 2):

Will this work for you?

```
SELECT (
    select count(pKey) = 1 from testable where pKey = 1 and prodStatus = 0
) AND (
    select count(pKey) = 1 from testable where pKey = 2 and prodStatus = 0
)
```

Check [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb3cc/2)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(pKey = 1) = 1 and SUM(pKey = 2) = 1
FROM testable
WHERE prodStatus = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 select Sum(case When (pKey = 1 And prodStatus = 0) Or 
                      (pKey = 2 and prodStatus = 0)
             Then 1 Else 0 End)
 from testable
```